# Is smooth slow motion physics possible with SpriteKit?

Tags: animation, sprite-kit, game-physics

Setting the speed property of `SKPhysicsWorld` to anything less than `1.0` slows the physics simulation, but does so in a way that results in staggered animations - like this...

[image]

Is there anyway to slow the simulation that would result in smooth animations?

Cheeky Bonus Question: If not, is this possible with any other 2D game engine?

Comment: How do you accomplish what's going on in your animation? Very cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution (provided that this behavior is normal and not caused by, for instance, updating the ball's position manually or via a move action) would be to design the game/physics so speed 1.0 represents the slowest game speed, while at "normal" speed the speed property might be, say, 4.0.

Comment: Yes, make gravity and all other forces (and damping?) smaller